# Sublime Text: Permission denied when running Sublime REPL by non-root user under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

When trying to run [Sublime REPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), I get a message box with *permission denied* error: `IOError(13, 'Permission denied')` unless I launch Sublime Text with root privileges (`sudo sublime`). It holds for any REPL language.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and Sublime resides in `/opt/` directory.

Since I can't google anyone else having this problem, probably there's something special about my filesystem privileges somewhere. What can cause files that Sublime REPL use be protected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ooof, that was silly. In `~/.config` folder with Sublime settings, `sublime-text-2` had `root root` owner, have no idea why. Had to change owner to myself with `chown`, and that's all.

Comment: `cd ~/.config; chown <username>:<username> sublime-text-2`

Comment: Geez! You can't imagine how much time I was looking for this answer. I'm running Linux Mint as guest of a Windows 7 host using VMWare and although the Shared Folders were correctly set I was unable to write/modify any file within Sublime because I was always receiving a Permission Denied error while other text editors (like GEdit) could write without problems. The only difference is I'm using ST3 and the folder name, obviously, changes too.

Comment: more precisely:  cd ~/.config; chown -R <username>:<username> sublime-text

Comment: @Bruno: Where can I find this file in Windows? I have a similar setup

Answer (score 2):

This [error](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/107) (reported on GitHub) may have some bearing on the behavior you're seeing.  If I were you, I'd try to isolate a specific use case and then add it to the bug report so wuub might be able to advise you.

Answer (score 1):

In your installation folder: opt/sublime_text

```
marcelo@ubuntu:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for marcelo: *******
root@ubuntu:/home/marcelo#
root@ubuntu:/home/marcelo# cd ..
root@ubuntu:/home# cd ..
root@ubuntu:/# cd opt/sublime_text
root@ubuntu:/opt/sublime_text# chmod 777 sublime_text
```

Done..

Answer (score 0):

[Reverting to a Freshly Installed State](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html) worked for me:

```
sudo mv ~/.config/sublime-text-3 ~/sublime-text-3
subl
```

It automatically creates a new copy of `~/.config/sublime-text-3` with your username as the owner. It should solve all the `Permission denied` kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Execute in the terminal

`sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.config/sublime-text-3/`

This will give all the permissions to the folders recursively

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's `sublime-text-3`, but sometimes it's `sublime-text`. The folder name may not be always the same. If `-3` does not work, check if you have `sublime-text` folder there. If yes, replace the content of that.